# build gradle wrapper failed, why?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I study programming and watch a lecture where my prof says in order to produce gradle wrapper I have to type "gradle wrapper" in terminal. I have mac and when I type in I get an error:

```
user-MBP propra % gradle wrapper
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Directory 'path' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

To create a new Gradle build in this directory run 'gradle init'

For more detail on the 'init' task see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

For more detail on creating a Gradle build see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

* Try:
> Run gradle init to create a new Gradle build in this directory.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Can someone help me? I am a newbie in programming

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you need a `settings.gradle` file in the directory.

The file can be empty.  Just create the required file, and try running the command again.